# Undo zcat to Internal HDD and recover the Data

Tags: hard-drive, usb-creator

I wanted to made a USB Ubuntu installer via zcat, because the T61s of my Dad don't have a CD Drive.

So i used "sudo zcat boot.img.gz > /dev/sdb"
But i forgot to change the sdb to sdc and overwrite my Mediastorrage.
Is there any possibility to undo that?

Thanks so far.

Comment: Do you remember exact sizes of the partitions?

Answer (score 2):

When a drive has been accidentally overwritten you will need [Data Recovery Tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) to restore the remainders of your data. After unpacking an image on your drive those parts of your drive where data were written are definitely lost and can not be recovered.

By installing [testdisk](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk] you may be able to recover parts of your files.

Included in the [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) suite you will also find the tool [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) that helps to recover individual files even in the case the partitions can not be restored by testdisk or the drive itself has a hardware defect.

TestDisk/PhotoRec can also be run on a backup image of your drive (strongly recommended).

Comment: Ah testdisk, I remembered there was another tool from the same creator, but I thought PhotoRec included that testdisk you mentioned. It is the other way around and that sounds logical :)

Comment: I always have to look it up first, I have to admit. That's why you beat me by 6 min. :)

Answer (score 1):

This always seems to happen just moments before someone decides to make regular backups of his system.

You may try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to save some of the files. Boot from a live CD, attach an extra external hard disk to store files on.