# How to recover 1 specific partition using live cd (usb)?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, data-recovery

So I have somehow managed to delete my Ubuntu partition. I think it may have been windows system restore that deleted it. Below is a screenshot of Gparted run via a live usb copy of Ubuntu. That big 59.64 GiB of unallocated space? That used to be my Ubuntu partition.

Is there any way I can easily recover just that partition? (Assuming that the data is still there, which I think it is). I believe it was Ext 4, and it was running Ubuntu 12.04 if that makes any difference.

[image: Gparted screenshot]

Comment: Check [this thread][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122296/undo-zcat-to-internal-hdd-and-recover-the-data

Comment: Testdisk may be able to completely recover partitions as long as nothing has been written to them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/recovering.html) link here can help you?